# Custom dynamic Twig template that extends Twig_Template

Tags: php, angularjs, templates, twig, phalcon

TL;DR: I am currently struggling with the idea how to elegantly generate CRUDs/GRID using Twig.

Long story:

I have a Phalcon app with AngularJs, templating system is Twig.
PHP is suppose to prepare a template for CRUD that contains:

- List od entities, table that contains proper headers, columns, row items, action buttons
- Simple and advanced search
- Mass actions block
- Main buttons - Add/Import/Export etc.

AngularJs is responsible for:

- Paginating results in 2 modes: Ajax Loaded entities, All entities at once
- Changing number of entities per page
- Displaying various forms in modals - Add/Edit/Import
- Filtering entities - simple and advanced search

Everything is working right now but I am not particularly fond of how it works.

For example a simple entity with few fields needs a following template:

```
{% extends 'index.twig' %}

{% block containerAttr %}ng-controller="InventoryController as ctrl"{% endblock %}

{% set ctrlName = 'ctrl' %}
{% set columnWidth = 'col-xs-12' %}
{% set tableClass = 'table table-bordered table-striped table-hover' %}

{% block header %}
    {% include '@crud/crud/header.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% embed '@crud/crud/main-box.twig' %}
        {% block tableHeader %}
            {% autoescape false %}
                {{ crud.tableHeader('Id', 'id') }}
                {{ crud.tableHeader('Nazwa', 'name') }}
                <th class="col-xs-1">Actions</th>
            {% endautoescape %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block tableRow %}
            <td ng-bind="e.id"></td>
            <td ng-bind="e.name"></td>
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
    {% embed '@crud/crud/form.twig' %}
        {% block modalBody %}
            {% autoescape false %}
                <div class="row">
                    {{ crud.input('ctrl.entity.name', 'Name', 12) }}
                </div>
            {% endautoescape %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
    {% embed '@crud/crud/upload.twig' %}{% endembed %}
    {% embed '@crud/crud/advancedSearch.twig' %}{% endembed %}
    <script>
        window.xdata = {{ xdata | json_encode | raw }};
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

`crud` in this template is responsible for generating form fields compatible with AngularJs.

Idea is: **To create new CRUDs/Grids with the least amount of work required. While still giving a room for some flexibility.**

Right now to make a CRUD/Grid inside my application there is a really little work required:
PHP Controller needs to contain only one line:

```
class SubCategoryController extends CrudBase
{
    protected $entityClass = InventoryCategory::class;
}
```

Thanks to extending it is really easy to customize every part of it.

Model needs to have just a few fields:

```
class InventoryCategory extends ModelBase
{
    /** @var integer */
    public $id;

    /** @var string */
    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('inventory_subcategory');
        $this::setup(['castOnHydrate' => true]);
    }
}
```

Even the AngularJs controller contains only URLs and one line:

```
class InventoryCategoryController extends CrudBase {
    constructor($injector, $scope) {
        super($injector, $scope);

        this.urlSave = '/inventory/category/save';
        this.urlImport = '/inventory/category/import';
        this.urlExport = '/inventory/category/export';
        this.urlDelete = '/inventory/category/delete';

        this.init({
            advancedSearch: false
        });
    }
}

angular.module('App').controller('InventoryCategoryController', InventoryCategoryController);
```

*Yes I use ES6, application is not compatible with older browsers anyways and it is admin panel so I do not care about older browsers.*

But now only templates remains a tedious work to copy it over and change it. Not to mention they do look pretty ugly.

So my idea was to use `Annotation Reader` (Phalcon has one) to read fields from `Model`, then transform it into a **base** configuration, check if there is custom configuration in json and merge it. Then based on configuration, generate this whole template on the fly.

**So the grand question is:**

I was wondering if I can create some class that extends `Twig_Template` to generate this template on the fly?

I have seen Twig cache and it should be pretty easy but then how can i use it? How can i render it? Will `extend` still work?

Comment: Don't think extending that class template is the correct angle. That class is in charge to convert twig code to php and not creating twig templates

Comment: @DarkBee I have checked it quickly and it seems like it CAN be used that way. I don't see in twig a better way to do this, and i don't want to create monstrous templates that will have all the logic inside.

Comment: Then what is your starting point if it's possible to generate `twig` file from inside that class?

Comment: No it is not possible to generate twig and it was not what i was after. I wanted that template to be automatically generated on the fly **using** twig. For each and every model. Of course you can make a twig that will read all the configuration from controller but it becomes monstrosity and it is absolutely unreadable.